# Asp.Net Web API outputcache with Redis not working

Tags: asp.net, web, redis, outputcache

1. Redis is running on windows (services -> Redis Server)
2. Web.config is configured

```xml
<caching>
 <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache" enableOutputCache="true" enableFragmentCache="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" type="microsoft.web.redis.redisoutputcacheprovider" host="127.0.0.1" port="6379"accesskey="" ssl="false" />
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

1. Output cache attribute is added to my Web Api controller

   [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60, ServerTimeSpan = 60)]
2. Caching is working, but Redis does not contain any key

   redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
   (empty list or set)
   redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
3. Also tried to register my custom output cache provider

   public override string GetOutputCacheProviderName(HttpContext context)
   {
    return "MyRedisOutputCache";
   }

Nothing helped :( 
Any idea?

Comment: I also have the same issue, if I run `redis-cli monitor` I only see bunch of `GET` requests but no `SET` at all. Strange! the same provider works just fine with a remote redis (eg. redislab), and the same redis installation is working great with other parts of the same application that uses StackExchange Redis client to store and retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to solve the problem by uninstalling an existing redis installation which became obsolete https://github.com/rgl/redis

If you installed redis from there, then read along...

I then installed `redis-64` from https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64 and it worked perfectly.

- Once installed via chocolatey, goto `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64` on an administrative command prompt or powershell and run the following command to register redis as windows service

  `redis-server --service-install redis.windows-service.conf --loglevel verbose`
- then create a folder `Logs` (without this the service won't start)
- run the service `redis-server --service-start`